# Apple pass (passbook/wallet) server bash error "Couldn't find required certificates" - what certificates exactly?

Tags: ios, bash, passbook, passkit

I am trying to setup a Apple's pass server (pass_server). I have put my pass p12 certificate and the new 2016 WWDRCA certificate in the pass_server/data/Certificate folder yet it does not recognise it. It prompts me for the hostname and the hostname works fine but this is what happens:

```
MBP:pass_server macbook$ lib/pass_server_ctl -s
Please enter the hostname or ip address for the server [2a92:c8f:543f:d510:8c5b:1f24:35b1:2934]:
MacBook-Pro.local
The hostname is set to MacBook-Pro.local


Couldn't find required certificates at /Users/user/Desktop/pass_server/Data/Certificate
Exiting
```

I have searched high and low and I have not seen anyone with a similar problem and I am finding that there is extremely limited amount of resources or tutorials for this. Does anyone know exactly how I can fix this?

Comment: Try renaming the folder to `pass_server/Data/Certificate` with a capital 'D'

Comment: @PassKit thanks, I have tried that but it did not work unfortunately, I double checked the oath and it is identical now.  "/Users/user/Desktop/pass_server/Data/Certificate"

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the pass_server_ctl file line from https://jsonip.com to http://jsonip.com and that fixed it.